# How do I make it so that my button stays highlighted until I do a second click on my grid

Tags: python, pygame

when I click one of my buttons you can see that the button is highlighted and a blue rectangle appears around it. Is there a way to make it so that the button stays like this until I click on my grid. I tried using a while loop so that it stayed that colour until a second click was registered however this just resulted in my program crashing. Thanks

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

class button():
    def __init__(self,screen,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,cc,text,text_colour):
        self.screen = screen
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.ic = ic
        self.colour = ic
        self.ac = ac
        self.cc = cc
        self.text = text
        self.text_colour = text_colour
        self.clicked = False
    def draw_button(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if self.x+self.w > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y+self.h > mouse[1] > self.y:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.ac,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
            if click[0]:
                self.clicked = True
            if self.clicked == True:
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.cc,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, blue,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h), 3)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.ic,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial black",20)
        text = font.render(self.text,True,(self.text_colour))
    #this code ensures it will be placed central in the button
        screen.blit(text,[self.x+self.w/2-(text.get_rect().w/2),self.y+self.h/2-(text.get_rect().h/2)])


# first we define some constants
# doing this will reduce the amount of 'magic' numbers throughout the code
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
grey = (125,125,125)
green = (0, 200, 0)
red = (200, 0, 0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,200)

grid_width = 40
grid_height = 40
cell = (grid_width, grid_height)

grid_margin = 5 # number of pixels between each cell

distance_from_left = 500 # number of pixels between the grid and the left and right of the screen
distance_from_top = 100 # number of pixels between the grid and the top and bottom of the screen

done = False # is our program finished running?


# create the screen and clock
screen_size = [1000,1000]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Djikstra's and A*")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

current_colour = white # which colour is active

# setting up the grid
# cells can be accessed by grid[row][col] ie. grid[3][4] is the 3rd row and 4th column
# each cell contains [x, y, colour]
# where x is the x position on the screen
#       y is the y position on the screen
#       colour is the current colour of the cell
grid = []
for y in range(10):
     row = []
     for x in range(10):
         row.append([x * (grid_width + grid_margin) + distance_from_left, y * (grid_height + grid_margin) + distance_from_top, white])
     grid.append(row)

# main loop
while not done:

    # process all events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: # did the user click the 'x' to close the screen
            done = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # get the position of the mouse
            mpos_x, mpos_y = event.pos

            # check if finish was clicked
            button_x_min, button_y_min, button_width, button_height = 75,250,100,50
            button_x_max, button_y_max = button_x_min + button_width, button_y_min + button_height
            if button_x_min <= mpos_x <= button_x_max and button_y_min <= mpos_y <= button_y_max:
                current_colour = red

            # check if start WAS CLICKED
            button_x_min, button_y_min, button_width, button_height = 75,150,100,50
            button_x_max, button_y_max = button_x_min + button_width, button_y_min + button_height
            if button_x_min <= mpos_x <= button_x_max and button_y_min <= mpos_y <= button_y_max:
                current_colour = green

            # check if blocked WAS CLICKED
            button_x_min, button_y_min, button_width, button_height = 75,350,100,50
            button_x_max, button_y_max = button_x_min + button_width, button_y_min + button_height
            if button_x_min <= mpos_x <= button_x_max and button_y_min <= mpos_y <= button_y_max:
                current_colour = grey

            # calculations for clicking cells

            mpos_x -= distance_from_left # mouse position relative to the upper left cell
            mpos_y -= distance_from_top # ^ same

            col = mpos_x // (grid_width + grid_margin) # which cell is the mouse clicking
            row = mpos_y // (grid_height + grid_margin) # ^ same

            # make sure the user clicked on the grid area
            if row >= 0 and col >= 0:
                try:
                    # calculate the boundaries of the cell
                    cell_x_min, cell_y_min =  col * (grid_height + grid_margin), row * (grid_width + grid_margin)
                    cell_x_max = cell_x_min + grid_width
                    cell_y_max = cell_y_min + grid_height
                    # now we will see if the user clicked the cell or the margin
                    if cell_x_min <= mpos_x <= cell_x_max and cell_y_min <= mpos_y <= cell_y_max:
                        grid[row][col][2] = current_colour if event.button == 1 else white
                    else:
                        # the user has clicked the margin, so we do nothing
                        pass
                except IndexError: # clicked outside of the grid
                    pass           # we will do nothing

    # logic goes here


    # drawing
    screen.fill(black)

    menu = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [0,0,300,1000])

    start = button(screen,75,150,100,50,green,bright_green,grey, "Start", white)
    start.draw_button()
    finish = button(screen,75,250,100,50,red,bright_red,grey,"Finished",white)
    finish.draw_button()
    blocked = button(screen,75,350,100,50,black,grey,green,"Blocked",white)
    blocked.draw_button()

    for row in grid:
        for x, y, colour in row:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (x, y, grid_width, grid_height))

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify things:

Add a method (`isOn`) to `class button` which cecks if the mouse is on the button:

```py
def isOn(self, mx, my):
    return self.x <= mx and mx < self.x + self.w and self.y <= my and my < self.y + self.h
```

Evaluate if the mouse is on the button when you draw the button. Evaluate the color of the button dependent on the click state (`self.clicked`) of the button and the mouse position:

```py
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
onSelf = self.isOn(mx, my)

color = self.ac if onSelf else self.cc if self.clicked else self.ic
pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
```

Full code of `class button`

```py
class button():
    def __init__(self,screen,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,cc,text,text_colour):
        self.screen = screen
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.ic = ic
        self.colour = ic
        self.ac = ac
        self.cc = cc
        self.text = text
        self.text_colour = text_colour
        self.clicked = False

    def isOn(self, mx, my):
        return self.x <= mx and mx < self.x + self.w and self.y <= my and my < self.y + self.h

    def draw_button(self):
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        onSelf = self.isOn(mx, my)

        color = self.ac if onSelf else self.cc if self.clicked else self.ic
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))

        if self.clicked == True: 
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, blue,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h), 3)

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial black",20)
        text = font.render(self.text,True,(self.text_colour))
        #this code ensures it will be placed central in the button
        screen.blit(text,[self.x+self.w/2-(text.get_rect().w/2),self.y+self.h/2-(text.get_rect().h/2)])
```

Further more, ist is sufficient to create the 3 buttons once, before the main loop do not crete new objects continuously in every frame.

Evaluate the click state of the buttons in the event handling loop:

```py
start.clicked   = start.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)
finish.clicked  = finish.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)
blocked.clicked = blocked.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)
```

Changes to the main loop:

```py
start = button(screen,75,150,100,50,green,bright_green,grey, "Start", white)
finish = button(screen,75,250,100,50,red,bright_red,grey,"Finished",white)
blocked = button(screen,75,350,100,50,black,grey,green,"Blocked",white)

# main loop
while not done:

    # process all events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: # did the user click the 'x' to close the screen
            done = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # get the position of the mouse
            mpos_x, mpos_y = event.pos

            start.clicked   = start.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)
            finish.clicked  = finish.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)
            blocked.clicked = blocked.isOn(mpos_x, mpos_y)

            # calculations for clicking cells

            # [...]

    # [...]

    # drawing
    screen.fill(black)

    menu = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [0,0,300,1000])

    start.draw_button()
    finish.draw_button()
    blocked.draw_button()

    for row in grid:
        for x, y, colour in row:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (x, y, grid_width, grid_height))

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```